# Difference between Template Parsing Finished and Total Execution Time in Debugging

Tags: performance, debugging

I'm having major performance issues and I'm trying to nail down the culprit. I'm on EE 2.7.1 with a number of add ons (All of P+T's, Structure, ect.) However, I'm getting pages loads in excess of 5 seconds or even more. While I was combing through the Debugging I noticed that while Template Parsing would say one number, the Total Execution Time would give another number, sometimes twice as long as the Template Parsing time.

Here is one example

```
(2.658272 / 43.45MB) Template Parsing Finished
Total Execution Time    5.4786
```

I must be misunderstanding something, but I would have thought those two to be very similar instead of so far apart. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

"Template parsing time" is only the time EE spent to render the page, but not the time creating connection to DB, runnning SQL queries, making system calls, etc.

Look at the SQL queries panel to see how many time is spent on each query. It should be a good start to understand why a page is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Also, look in the debugging and watch for a jump in execution time.  You will see pairs of numbers in the brackets that are the execution time and memory, and anything that is really slowing things down will show up as a jump in time.

For example:

(0.454163 / 21.26MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Pt_field_pack_ext/channel_entries_tagdata 
(2.519405 / 21.13MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Playa_ext/channel_entries_tagdata

Here you would note that the execution time has jumped by 2 seconds from one item to the next and you can look at what was being done at that time.